# Disable the usage of Camera while Phone is locked

Tags: lock-screens, camera, buttons

The phone Kyocera KC-S701 has a hardware button to start the camera application. Sometimes the button is pressed by accident while the phone is carried within my pocket. Is there a possibility to disable the camerabutton while the phone is locked?

Comment: Android version? Is the device rooted? You can remap the camera button automatically when the device is locked.  [Xposed Additons Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb.pro) or  [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) (needs Tasker) can do that easily.

Comment: It's Android 4.4.2 and the device is not rooted. I thought there might be an menu options, but i'll look at the addons